# What's the difference between de and dw in vim?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

Following `vimtutor` tips I found the following in Lesson 2.3:

```
Many commands that text are made from an operator and a motion.
The format for a  follows:

      d   motion

Where:
  d      - is the delete operator.
  motion - is what the operator will operate on (listed below).

A short list of motions:
  w - until the start of the next word, EXCLUDING its first character.
  e - to the end of the current word, INCLUDING the last character.
  $ - to the end of the line, INCLUDING the last character.
```

However, I don't see the difference between <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> and <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>. What's the use case when using <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> and <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>?

Comment: How are the periods handled?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Having a buffer like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor
```

Move the cursor (`▒`) in the middle of `ipsum` word:

```
Lorem ip▒um dolor
```

Now press <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>:

```
Lorem ip▒dolor
```

The cursor deleted the letters from the current word, until end, but without space.

When doing <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>, the space will be deleted:

```
Lorem ip▒olor
```

Answer (score 27):

`dw` means "cut from here to next word".

```
before: fo[o]bar baz
        dw
after:  fo[b]az
```

`de` means "cut from here to the end of the current word".

```
before: fo[o]bar baz
        de
after:  fo[ ]baz
```